Issue with converting UTC to a specific timezone in Jython
I am facing a problem with a Jython script used for timezone conversion. The script is used to convert the current UTC time to the 'America/Los_Angeles' timezone. However, when executing the script in the IST timezone (in which I am working), it incorrectly returns the time in IST rather than in the 'America/Los_Angeles' timezone."
Here is my script:
from java.util import Calendar, TimeZone

def convert_utc_to_timezone(tz):
    # Get the current time in UTC
    utc_calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    utc_time_in_millis = utc_calendar.getTimeInMillis()
    
    # Create a calendar for the target time zone and set the time in milliseconds
    target_calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz))
    target_calendar.setTimeInMillis(utc_time_in_millis)
    
    # Get the time in the target time zone
    target_time = target_calendar.getTime()
    return target_time

tz = "America/Los_Angeles"
converted_time = convert_utc_to_timezone(tz)
print("Converted Time: " + converted_time.toString())

Could someone please advise why the output remains in the IST time zone instead of the "America/Los_Angeles" time zone? And how can I rectify this issue?

Formatting can be used in jython for converting the time to a specific timezone.
Example:
from java.util import Date, TimeZone
from java.text import SimpleDateFormat

def convert_utc_to_timezone(tz):
    
    # Get the current time
    currentTime = Date()

    # Format the time to the given time zone and return it
    dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz)
    return dateFormat.format(currentTime)

# Get the local time converted to Los Angeles time and print it
tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
convertedTime = convert_utc_to_timezone(tz)
print "Converted time:", convertedTime

To get a comprehensive list of possible timezone arguments for the function, this script can be used:
from java.util import TimeZone

# Get the list of available time zones
availableTimeZones = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()

# Print the list of available time zones
for timeZone in availableTimeZones:
    print timeZone


but, here this function 'convert_utc_to_timezone(tz)' return datetime in string format, which should be in datetime format.

@ravvi , under the hood, a Java date datatype is going to be UTC no matter what. It will display as the local time of the computer it's running on unless it's formated in some other way. What are you doing with this date?

In our code we have to store the current_datetime to Snowflake, In Snowflake the timezone is Americal/Los_Angeles
